# Invalid Operation Exception on opening Child Form

Tags: vb.net, gecko

After I added the following code in my `VB.NET` Project child form's `InitializeComponents()`:

```
Skybound.Gecko.Xpcom.Initialize(Application.StartupPath & "\SuperGecko\xulrunner-1.9.1.11.en-US.win32\xulrunner")
Gecko.GeckoPreferences.User("security.warn_viewing_mixed") = False
Gecko.GeckoPreferences.User("plugin.state.flash") = 0
```

I am getting this Error when I try to open this Child form from MDI Parent form:

`Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.`

If I remove the code from `InitializeComponents()` another Error pops out while opening the form:
`Couldn't not find XULRunner in` *myxulrunnerpath*

But the path is correct and  I tried to put that code on Form_Load event, but It still desn't work.

What can be the cause?

Comment: Why are you adding code to the `InitializeComponent` method at all?  That method is generated - and regenerated - by the Windows Forms designer.  If you want to add code to the form's initialisation then you put it in the constructor, AFTER the call to `InitializeComponent`, or in the `Load` event handler.

Comment: In C# there is a call for `InitializeComponent();` before the `Form_Load`, but where in VB.NET I can find the call for `InitializeComponent`?

Comment: In C# there is a call to `InitializeComponent` in the constructor and it's in exactly the same place in VB.  The difference is that the default constructor is implicit in VB.  If you want to add code to the constructor then simply type `Public Sub New()` and hit Enter.  The IDE will complete the method, including a call to `InitializeComponent`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using one or more Web Browsers in your windows Form, they all need to have the same version and need to be the same kind. For example, if one is `Gecko` and another one is `Skybound` or other, it may not work.